# Azure’s equivalent of AWS Macie

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure

The organisation where I work has a huge data footprint(several thousands terabytes). This data is first stored centrally on an ADLS Gen2 service from where other teams copy in data specific to their requirements. One of the challenges we are facing is to keep track of PII data. Human intervention becomes a huge bottleneck in this case, and we are looking for some intelligent solution which can send alerts or at least identify such data. Does Azure have an equivalent of [AWS Macie](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/macie/latest/userguide/macie-classify-objects-pii.html)? I looked into Azure Security Center, but I couldn't find it relevant for this use case. Could you please advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [Azure Purview](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5002404)

Comment: Can it detect and categorize PII data?

Comment: @SouravA yes, you can do so through labelling https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/create-sensitivity-label